# Filtering array result

Tags: php, arrays

My array :

```
<?php

$hoppa = array
(
    "0" => array
        ("0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"),
    "1" => array
        ("0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"),      
    "2" => array
        ("1","0","0","1","0","0","0","0","0","0"),
    "3" => array
        ("1","0","0","1","0","1","1","1","1","0"),
    "4" => array
        ("1","1","1","1","0","0","0","0","1","0"),
    "5" => array
        ("1","0","0","1","0","1","1","1","1","0"),
    "6" => array
        ("1","0","0","1","0","1","0","0","1","0"),
    "7" => array
        ("1","0","0","1","0","1","1","1","1","0"),
    "8" => array
        ("0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"),
    "9" => array
        ("0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0")                                   

);

?>
```

My array's output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 0
            [3] => 0
            [4] => 0
            [5] => 0
            [6] => 0
            [7] => 0
            [8] => 0
            [9] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 0
            [3] => 0
            [4] => 0
            [5] => 0
            [6] => 0
            [7] => 0
            [8] => 0
            [9] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 0
            [3] => 1
            [4] => 0
            [5] => 0
            [6] => 0
            [7] => 0
            [8] => 0
            [9] => 0
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 0
            [3] => 1
            [4] => 0
            [5] => 1
            [6] => 1
            [7] => 1
            [8] => 1
            [9] => 0
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [3] => 1
            [4] => 0
            [5] => 0
            [6] => 0
            [7] => 0
            [8] => 1
            [9] => 0
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 0
            [3] => 1
            [4] => 0
            [5] => 1
            [6] => 1
            [7] => 1
            [8] => 1
            [9] => 0
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 0
            [3] => 1
            [4] => 0
            [5] => 1
            [6] => 0
            [7] => 0
            [8] => 1
            [9] => 0
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 0
            [3] => 1
            [4] => 0
            [5] => 1
            [6] => 1
            [7] => 1
            [8] => 1
            [9] => 0
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 0
            [3] => 0
            [4] => 0
            [5] => 0
            [6] => 0
            [7] => 0
            [8] => 0
            [9] => 0
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 0
            [3] => 0
            [4] => 0
            [5] => 0
            [6] => 0
            [7] => 0
            [8] => 0
            [9] => 0
        )

)
```

it will give 0 (zero) as result

```
echo $hoppa[1][1];
```

it will give 1 (one) as result

```
echo $hoppa[2][0];
```

I dont want 0 (zero) values to show in the results. I want php script to return only 1 as results. Which functions should use? or can you give me a sample?

Comment: You don't want your code to output anything if the value is 0. That is my understanding of your question. Am I correct?

Comment: @Babak Naffas, yes. thats what i want. i wanna use print_r($hoppa); and get only 1 values.

Comment: According to the documentation, you're looking at the wrong function. http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php

Comment: @Babak Naffas ,thanks for your help. my problem has been resolved. sory for my broken english :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
foreach($hoppa as $k => $v) {
    $hoppa[$k] = array_filter($v);
}
```

This results in:

```
php > print_r($hoppa);
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [3] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [3] => 1
            [5] => 1
            [6] => 1
            [7] => 1
            [8] => 1
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [3] => 1
            [8] => 1
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [3] => 1
            [5] => 1
            [6] => 1
            [7] => 1
            [8] => 1
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [3] => 1
            [5] => 1
            [8] => 1
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [3] => 1
            [5] => 1
            [6] => 1
            [7] => 1
            [8] => 1
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
        )

)
```